# Force close on starting intent and the activity is mentioned in the android manifest

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclicklistener, forceclose

When I press the button linked to this class, I get a force close.  Here's the class:

```
public class Introduction extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.introstartbutton);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), QuestionOne.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the LogCat

```
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz/com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionOne}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionOne; no empty constructor
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionOne; no empty constructor
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
09-19 20:40:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(28122):    ... 11 more
```

Here's the Android Manifest

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Introduction"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionOne"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Result"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I'm hoping this'll sort out any future problems with this too.  I've googled a far bit too but I can't make proper sense of the logcat except for the keywords.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:  Here's QuestionOne.java

```
public class QuestionOne extends Results {

    public QuestionOne(int score) {
        super(score);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        score = super.score;
    }

    RadioButton answer1, answer2, answer3;
    Button oneNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);

        RadioGroup answerGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.oneradiogroup);
        final int index = answerGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(answerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

        Button oneNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onenext);

        oneNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent questionTwo = new Intent("com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionTwo");
                switch(index) {
                case 1 : score = score + 10; // y is the score of the second answer
                startActivity(questionTwo);
                break;
                case 2 : score = score + 20; // z is the score of the third answer
                startActivity(questionTwo);
                break;
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here's the Results class:

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    public int score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView textScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textScore.setText("Your score is " + score);
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public Results(int score) {
        this.score = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post what QuestionOne is?

Comment: Don't add constructors to any class which extends `Activity`. The only use for a constructor is if you use something like `MyClass x = new MyClass(y);` and you cannot create an instance of an `Activity` using `new` in that way. The Android OS will create your `Activity` for you.

Comment: But eclipse is telling me I need a constructor or it gives me a red error

Comment: Remove the constructor from `Results` and change the definition of `score` in `Results` to `int score = 0;` Also you haven't set your content view in `Results` so `findViewById(...)` is going to fail for the `TextView`....and you haven't called `super.onCreate(...)` in `onCreate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just what the error says:

> can't instantiate class com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionOne; no empty constructor

Since you haven't posted your `QuestionOne` class, I can't give you an exact code. But, I would suspect you have something like this:

```
public class QuestionOne extends Activity {
    public QuestionOne(someType someParam) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, you must create a constructor which has *no* params. That is, `public QuestionOne() {`.

If you need to pass data to your second `Activity`, you will need to use [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) extras.

Comment: I have posted question one if it will help with my answer.

Comment: @MiKenning Yup, I was right. you have `public QuestionOne(int score)`. You cannot do this, your constructor MUST take zero arguments.

Comment: But when I remove that I get an error which says I must add a constructor :(

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't. But, if that's the case, use: `public QuestionOne() { super(); }`.

Comment: @Eric : See my comment on the OP's question. Basically don't create constructors for anything which extends `Activity`.

Comment: @Squonk His code extends `Activity` indirectly, though, so Eclipse would enforce such a restriction.

Comment: @Eric : Sorry I don't get your logic. My point is that constructors are redundant when it comes to anything which extends `Activity` either directly or indirectly. To all intents and purposes the point of entry is `onCreate(...)`. The only use for a constructor in a 'normal' class is when using `new MyClass(...)` which isn't how an `Activity` is created. You could override the parameterless constructor (bearing in mind it's the only one the OS will call) but a call to the `super` constructor would be needed (as you mention above) but why do it? `onCreate(...)` should be the entry point.

Comment: @Squonk I don't have my ADK set up on here, so I can't provide an example. But there seem to be cases (as the OP said above) where Eclipse forces you to have a constructor, even though `new QuestionOne()` is never called. I really don't have much more info on this, I'm just sure it's how this problem needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Eric : I have around 10 Activities in the app I'm currently working on and have developed a number of other apps, each having several Activities, and I've never come across a situation where Eclipse has thrown an error relating to constructors. I have Activities which directly extend `Activity` and I have Activities which extend those Activities...at no point do any of them have a constructor.

Comment: @Squonk I've never encountered it either. But what other explanation is there for the OP's comment of "*an error which says I must add a constructor*"?

Comment: @Eric : The OP hasn't given us all of the information or all of the code perhaps?